# Row wise Sorting in R

Tags: r

I would like to how to do a row wise sorting in csv using R. Here's the following data I have

```
Name  English Math  French
John    56    78    86
Sam     79    97    86
Viru    93    44    34
```

I want to perform row wise sorting for the above dataset. Like the following.

```
Name  
John   French  86   Math 78  English 56 
Sam    Math    97   French 86 English 79  
Viru    English 93   Math 44   French 34
```

Please do let me know how to approach

Comment: Do you want to create new columns with the column names?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we need only to `sort` by rows, use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` and assign the output back to the original columns after transposing the output.

```
df1[-1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, 
        FUN=function(x) sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)))

df1
#   Name English Math French
# 1 John      86   78     56
# 2  Sam      97   86     79
# 3 Viru      93   44     34
```

NOTE: But we may need to change the column names as sorting by row gives the new sorted values.

---

Another option will be use `apply` separately to get the column names and the values, with `Map` we get the corresponding columns, `cbind` with the first column to have the output.

```
nMat <- `dim<-`(names(df1)[-1][t(apply(df1[-1], 1,  
        order, decreasing=TRUE))], dim(df1[-1]))
vMat <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1,  sort, decreasing=TRUE))
cbind(df1[1], data.frame(Map(cbind, as.data.frame(nMat,
   stringsAsFactors=FALSE), as.data.frame(vMat))))
#  Name    V1.1 V1.2   V2.1 V2.2    V3.1 V3.2
#1 John  French   86   Math   78 English   56
#2  Sam    Math   97 French   86 English   79
#3 Viru English   93   Math   44  French   34
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`.  We `melt` the 'wide' format to 'long' format, grouped by 'Name', we `order` the 'value' in decreasing order in 'i', get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), create a new column ('N'), grouped by 'Name' and use `dcast` to convert from 'long' to 'wide'.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var='Name')[order(-value), 
  .SD, Name][, N:=paste0("Col", 1:.N) , .(Name)],
    Name~N, value.var=c("variable", "value"))
#   Name variable_Col1 variable_Col2 variable_Col3 value_Col1 value_Col2 value_Col3
#1: John        French          Math       English         86         78         56
#2:  Sam          Math        French       English         97         86         79
#3: Viru       English          Math        French         93         44         34
```

**EDIT:**
The above `data.table` solution will not work in case you have 10 or more columns with values, because then `col10` will preceed `col2` in the ordering, even though higher values will be stored in `col2`. To resolve this issue, you can use just number for the names of your new columns as in:

```
dcast(melt(setDT(df1), id.var='Name')[order(-value), 
      .SD, Name][, N:=1:.N , .(Name)],
        Name~N, value.var=c("variable", "value"))
```

Comment: this is just sorting - OP wants the data to include the header

Comment: @akrun, I'm afraid your solution is producing some wrong results. For example, Sam's Math score was 97 and English 79 in the data provided by OP. It's 86 and 97 in your answer.

Comment: @Akrun Thanks for the response. Both the methods worked perfectly as expected. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
cbind(x[1],matrix(paste(colnames(x)[apply(x[,2:4],1,order,decreasing=TRUE)+1],
      apply(x[,2:4],1,sort,decreasing=TRUE)),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE))
#  Name          1         2          3
#1 John  French 86   Math 78 English 56
#2  Sam    Math 97 French 86 English 79
#3 Viru English 93   Math 44  French 34
```