# How to sort each row within a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

What is the `data.table` way of sorting values within each row? I can easily write a loop which does the sorting row by row, but I suppose it's not a very smart way of doing things.

Example:

Let's have a `data.table` like:

```
df = data.table(ID = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'),
                v1 = c(1,2,1,3,4,5),
                v2 = c(2,3,6,1,0,2),
                v3 = c(0,0,1,2,3,5))
```

I can sort this using a `for loop` like so:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  df[i, 2:4] = sort(df[i, 2:4], decreasing = T)
}
```

And it gives the intended result of:

```
   ID v1 v2 v3
1:  a  2  1  0
2:  b  3  2  0
3:  c  6  1  1
4:  d  3  2  1
5:  e  4  3  0
6:  f  5  5  2
```

But it seems to be very slow way of doing things.

Comment: A `data.frame` (and therefore `data.table` and `tibble`) is really meant to deal with *columns* of information; migration of data across columns is counter to their efficiencies and design. Can it be done? Sure, but you're working outside of how frames are structured. If it were a `matrix` it would be much more straight-forward, since it works as efficiently row-wise as it does column-wise.

Comment: Possible duplicte, related posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6063881/680068 
 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/35891340/680068

Comment: Let us know if akrun's data.table solution works for you in the links, then we could close this post as duplicate.

Comment: Oh, I missed the akrun's answer, saw just the first question you linked to before i asked my question. Awesome, thank you. Do you have any advice on the efficiency of the solution? i.e. is it better to convert the object to matrix/data.frame and then sort or use akrun's solution for `data.table`?

Comment: @zx8754 Akrun's solution works. should i close or delete completely?

Comment: Please do not delete, it is good to have duplicated posts.

Comment: @zx8754 Actually, it feels like akrun's solution sorts by a column name (which is a string), so it will not work as is for a table with a lot of columns. It will produce order of columns like, say: `Col1   Col10 Col100 Col101 Col102 Col103 Col104 Col105 Col106 Col107 Col108 Col109`  and then continue `Col11 Col110 Col111 Col112 Col113 Col114 Col115 Col116 Col117 Col118 Col119   Col12 Col120 Col121`. But the order of values in row is thus not correct. It can be fixed by not using the characters in front of column number.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer there **or** suggest edit to akrun's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I suggested an edit to the original answer.

Comment: For future readers: this is what akrun's answer looks like for the above dataset: `dcast(melt(df, id.var='ID')[order(-value), .SD, ID][, N := 1:.N , .(ID)], ID~N, value.var=c("value"))`

Comment: This question is different from that asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891340/row-wise-sorting-in-r although Akrun's answer includes this one. 
In this question, is it asked how to sort by using "data.table". It is important in terms of the google search key. You should not close the questions to the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use `data.table`? What about a base R `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` approach?

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) sort(x, decreasing = T)))
df
#  ID v1 v2 v3
#1  a  2  1  0
#2  b  3  2  0
#3  c  6  1  1
#4  d  3  2  1
#5  e  4  3  0
#6  f  5  5  2
```

Comment: They want data.table, if it was dataframe then I'd close as duplicate.

Comment: See akrun's answer in the links, it has data.table answer, with slightly different requirement, but could be relevant.

Comment: Good avoidance of the up-conversion to `character` when you excluded the first non-numeric column. To the casual reader, it may appear that it was excluded just because it was not intended to be sorted, but if non-numeric and numeric columns are passed together in the first argument of `apply`, they will all end up `character`, so (1) follow-up data will be different classes, and (2) sorts will be by alpha, not numeric, likely not what you want.

Comment: Ah yes @zx8754 you're right; looks like a dupe, akrun's answer gives a nice `data.table` solution. You should close. I'm happy to delete but perhaps these comments+explanations are use useful?