# How to sort entries in row of a tibble in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

As an example:

```
     V1    V2    V3     X
1     1     5     4    "asa"
2     5     2     3    "sdsf"
```

should become

```
     V1    V2    V3     X
1     1     4     5    "asa"
2     2     3     5    "sdsf"
```

Looking for short and fast solutions. It takes quite a while with a for loop and base R commands for a dataframe with ~150,000 rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row wise Sorting in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891340/row-wise-sorting-in-r)

Comment: i.e. if you want to sort only the numbers, convert the number bit to a matrix first. matrix computations are generally very fast in R

Answer (score 2):

```
d <- data.frame(
  a=c(1,3),
  b=c(5,2),
  c=c(9,1),
  d=c("as","dasd")
)

d

  a b c    d
1 1 5 9   as
2 3 2 1 dasd

as.data.frame(t(d)) %>% mutate_all(sort) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()

   V1 V2 V3   V4
V1  1  5  9   as
V2  1  2  3 dasd
```

Of course, the column names of the initial data frame become meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

You could pivot it, arrange the rows by size, and then pivot it back again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(V1:V3) %>%
  arrange(row_id, value) %>%
  group_by(row_id) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0("V", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = X:row_id, names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  select(-row_id)
```